# Building custom small sized TCPDUMP executable in order 100 to 300KB

Tags: linux, build, build-process, tcpdump

I need to build a small size tcpdump for the embedded project that I am working on. Since the memory size of my embedded device is limited, I need to strip all the unwanted functionality in the TCPDUMP while building it. My target is make the tcpdump executable size less that 300KB. After using "strip tcpdump option" and disabling package options in the configure, I have reached 750KB. To achieve this, I want to remove all the protocol decoding capability of tcpdump. I want the tcpdump to have no more that hex dump capability. I have a below initial list of unwanted protocols that has to be removed.

```
print-802_11.c
print-802_15_4.c
print-ah.c
print-ahcp.c
print-aodv.c
print-aoe.c
print-ap1394.c
print-atalk.c
print-atm.c
print-babel.c
print-bootp.C
print-bt.c
print-calm-fast.c
print-carp.c
print-cdp.c
print-cfm.c
print-chdlc.c
print-cip.c
print-cnfp.c
print-dccp.c
print-decnet.c
print-dtp.c
print-dvmrp.c
print-eap.c
print-egp.c
print-eigrp.c
print-enc.c
print-esp.c
print-fddi.c
print-forces.c
print-ipx.c
print-isakmp.c
print-isoclns.c
print-juniper.c
print-krb.c
print-lane.c
print-m3ua.c
print-sip.c
print-sl.c
print-sll.c
print-sunatm.c
print-zephyr.c
print-usb.c
print-vjc.c
print-vqp.c
print-timed.c
print-tipc.c
print-token.c
```

I started to remove these from Makefile.in  and removing the function calls manually in the source code. But then I realized this approach is not scalable.

Is there a better way to do this ? Someway by using configure options?

I am new to this. So please explain.

Comment: which library you are using for building tcpdump? uclibc?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to do this ? Someway by using configure options?

No, there are no such configure options.  You'll have to do it the non-scalable way.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to remove all the protocol decoding capability of tcpdump. I
>   want the tcpdump to have no more that hex dump capability. [...] Is
>   there a better way to do this ?"

I think there is, but with a very different approach.

If all you want from `tcpdump` is:

- the capability of specifying an interface,
- put this interface on promiscuous mode or not, or monitor mode if it's a Wi-Fi interface,
- apply a capture filter,
- and then spit the output in a file or as hex to stdout,

**...you'd be better write your own from scratch, using `libpcap`** (which is what `tcpdump` uses BTW).

This should be no more than 100-400 lines of C code depending on the options you want to have, you'll have a very, *very* small executable, and no more dependencies than `tcpdump` which require `libpcap` anyway. All the complexity is in the dissection, once you remove all that, what you have is basically... a `pcap` loop.

It's not that hard, and looks to me as far less work than your approach - and also more interesting work.

There's a tutorial to start with (30-60 minutes read):

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

...at the end of this tutorial, you'll already have the core of your program.

And you can find loads of info (and ask questions) in the related SO tags:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/libpcap/info

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pcap/info

...and have about 70 well-written man pages documenting the full `pcap` API (you'll end up using maybe 10-20 of these).